# What does "No such file or directory" on lsusb -t command imply?

Tags: usb, 22.04

After a linux-firmware package update.

My USB 3 ports are no longer working for any USB device (2 or 3).

Ubuntu 22.04.1 Kernels 4.9 & 6.1.

lsusb -t lists the devices but the system does not want to use them.

When using lsusb -t to see the devices I also get several error lines displayed:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/rx_lanes: No such file or device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/tx_lanes: No such file or device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/rx_lanes: No such file or device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/tx_lanes: No such file or device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/rx_lanes: No such file or device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/tx_lanes: No such file or device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/rx_lanes: No such file or device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/tx_lanes: No such file or device
```

I have no idea if these messages are normal or related to my USB issue.

What do these messages mean or imply?

Do I need to fix something?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS you tagged uses the 5.15 kernel (GA) or 5.19 kernel (HWE) yet you mention something else?  What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 with a modified 4.9 kernel.  The system has been running fine with this kernel since the launch of 22.04.0.  The other system is also running 22.04 but with a more recent kernel 6.1. It too has been running fine for quite some time.

Comment: `strace lsusb -t`  it will be long but find the error code/exit and see what is shown just before it.  Probably the driver link is missing

Comment: I ran the strace and it shows an openat() returning -1 for those devices.  So affirms those files are not present.  Should these files or links to them exist?

Comment: Running Ubuntu 22.04 with an ancient kernel (4.9) is not supported. I guess you're mostly on your own here.. 